# Comparing the same list without redundancy

Tags: java, foreach

I have this code

```
public void update(List<GameObject> objects) {
        for (GameObject object1 :objects){
        for (GameObject object2 : objects){
            if (!object1.equals(object2)) object1.collisionHandling(object2);
        }
    }
```

I need to compare all the items but I obviously don't want to compare each list item with itself; so item 1 and item 1 and I also don't want to compare item 2 with 3 and then on the next loop 3 with 2, etc.
Most of the examples use numbered arrays for (i=0, i<5, i++) but I have a list.
How would I go about making this code more efficient?

---

EDIT: I can now ignore the same items on the loop just need to stop symmetrical comparisons. 2-3, 3-2 etc.

Comment: please tag java, and use indexing. `List` interface has `get` method.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: `if (object1 == object2) { continue; }`

Comment: Thank you @MarcoAcierno changes have been made. Now just symmetrical comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do such a triangular comparison is:

```
for (int indexI = 0; indexI < objects.size(); indexI++) {
    GameObject object1 = objects.get(indexI);
    for (int indexJ = indexI + 1; indexJ < objects.size(); indexJ++) {
       GameObject object2 = objects.get(indexJ);
       object1.collisionHandling(object2);
    }
}
```

note that indexJ goes from indexI + 1 to size().

Comment: The limit in the first line should be (objects.size() - 1).

Comment: Does this work in a way if the number of objects changes (it's a game of asteroids so a bullet can be fired at any time and a collision may make a single asteroid split into 3 new separate asteroid objects) it will still work?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: As long as you don't change the size of the list while you're checking for collisions, the comparison works.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : If you like, but when indexI is size - 1, then indexJ = size() so the inner loop is not evaluated. I guess you save one 'get' call, in theory, but still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 streams and even consider parallel streams.

Requires you implement the Comparable interface in your `GameObject`.

```
public void update(List<GameObject> objects) {
    objects.parallelStream().forEach(
        object1 -> objects.parallelStream().filter(
            object2 -> object1 != object2 && object1.compareTo(object2) < 0
        ).forEach(
            object2 -> object1.collisionHandling(object2)
        )
    );
}
```

The output will be:

```
3 collision 4
2 collision 3
2 collision 4
0 collision 3
0 collision 2
1 collision 2
1 collision 4
1 collision 3
0 collision 1
0 collision 4
```

Or when using stream in stead of parallelStream:

```
0 collision 1
0 collision 2
0 collision 3
0 collision 4
1 collision 2
1 collision 3
1 collision 4
2 collision 3
2 collision 4
3 collision 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Java 8 you can just implement the `Comparable` interface in your `GameObject` and use this code:

```
public void update(List<GameObject> objects) {
    for(GameObject object1 : objects) {
        for(GameObject object2 : objects) {
            if(object1 != object2 && object1.compareTo(object2) < 0) {
                object1.collisionHandling(object2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```